# Display image from web server in C

Tags: c, image, file, webserver, server

I am coding a web server on C. I am able to view HTML and txt files however I am unable to view image files.

All I get is a error "The image “http://localhost:8080/images/image.jpg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

```
    if(strstr(method, "GET") != NULL)
    {
        f = fopen(url+1, "rb");

        if(f != NULL)
        {
            strncat(response, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n", 20);

            if(strstr(url, ".html") || strstr(url, ".htm"))
            {
                strncat(response, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", 30); 
            }

            else if(strstr(url, ".txt"))
            {
                strncat(response, "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n", 30); 
            }

            else if(strstr(url, ".jpg") || strstr(url, ".jpeg"))
            {
                strncat(response, "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n", 30); 
            }

            filesize = stat(url+1, &st);
        filesize = st.st_size;

        strncat(response, "Content-Length: 67210\r\n\r\n", 40); 
        while(fread(text,1 , 1, f))
        {
        strncat(response, text, filesize);
        }

printf("%d\n", strlen(text));
printf("%d\n", strlen(response));

            write(client_fd, response, strlen(response)); /*-1:'\0'*/
            fclose(f);
        }

        else
        {
            write(client_fd, not_found_response, strlen(not_found_response)); /*-1:'\0'*/
        } 
    }

    else
    {
        write(client_fd, bad_request_response, strlen(bad_request_response)); /*-1:'\0'*/
    }

    close(client_fd);
}
```

EDIT: I have edited my codes with the suggestions below. However I am still having the same problem. I have checked the filesize and it is 67210 but when I do strlen(response) I only get 66882. I am still missing some could that be the problem?

Comment: your use of strncat does not provide any safety.  You might as well use strcat.

Comment: Binary files probably have embedded `'\0'`. You should not use *string* functions with binary data.

Comment: 80 for a jpeg is very short

Comment: You have to add  a header with the content len `Content-Length:XXXX`

Answer (score 1):

The errors are probably creeping in during the `fgets`. `fgets` is useful for reading text, but not so much for binary data.  Use `fread` instead, and don't do the silly seek to the end trick to find the size of the data; just read to the end and write the data into the response.  To get the size of the file for the header, use `stat` or `fstat`.

Comment: Thanks for the help I changed to using fread instead but I am still getting the same error. fread(text, sizeof(text), 1, f);.

Comment: You want `fread(text, 1, sizeof(text), f)`.  Check the return value, which will tell you the number of items successfully read.  By putting sizeof(text) first, you are truncating data at the end of the file.

Comment: now i am using stat to get the filesize  and added Content-Length to my header, but I am still getting the same error. fread(text,filesize , 1, f); is my fread reading all the content?

Comment: Have you do a network capture to check if all the file is send and if the content length is correct ?

Comment: I am not to sure how to do a network capture to check if all my files are sent, but I tried a HTML file and I was able to display that. And yes the content length is correct I checked it with against the actual filesize.

Comment: If you want to know if fread is getting all the content, check its return value.    You're probably better off just using `fgetc` in a loop, though.