# Byte ordering HTTP Client

Tags: c, http, client

I wrote a simple HTTP Client that can request data from a host.

I am using getaddrinfo(3). With "GET / HTTP/1.1" request I am able to download HTML page of a given http Host.

Here is a part of my code:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *ai;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // Internet Protocol (IP) socket
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP 

int res = getaddrinfo("example.com", "http", &hints, &ai);
if (res != 0)
    ERROR_EXIT("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(res));

int sockfd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
if (sockfd < 0)
    ERROR_EXIT("socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));

if (connect(sockfd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen) < 0)
    ERROR_EXIT("connect: %s\n", strerror(errno));

FILE *sockfile = fdopen(sockfd, "r+");
if (sockfile == NULL)
    ERROR_EXIT("fdopen: %s\n", strerror(errno));

// send a GET request to the server:
if (fputs("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n", sockfile) == EOF)
    ERROR_EXIT("fputs: %s\n", strerror(errno));
if (fflush(sockfile) == EOF)
    ERROR_EXIT("fflush: %s\n", strerror(errno));

char buf[1024];

// print the reply:
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), sockfile) != NULL)
    fputs(buf, stdout);

fclose(sockfile);
return 0;
```

Downloading a HTML page works ok, but downloading PNG image for example `"GET /image.png HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"` gives something like this:

```
???????ݹh??DHǱ?yW]%?9a??J?6F?Ѧ?E???ݐTd?US?:)??I??M,?-????=??U??&???Nr? ???б??? 
b??]??8?6+?;??i䂢d?G?WA?rԺ?H[??]?Z5????g?{8??i\?qAC?@c??v.?rb??'<?T?????O?z? 
q,yĜ?ŷZI???X??fM?l?Z??l:;M???ۦ?????c?\\?W6+???o?}_???紈A??GvG?p??6{??{%?????0?{? 
%??ژ??l?$r<?????ft*'W?N?m߂Ҿ4??E?:^?#?&?%%
????Dw??Z?$??1?4?l%&2?f-5!?? ?E? 8...
```

I understand that this is a byte transfer and that I have to do byte ordering, but don't know where to begin.

I know that I need to use ntohl(3) and Big-endian order for PNG images. Can Someone give me directions what to look up and how to approach this?

Do I save this output to .png file and then do byte order or do I do before I create a .png file?

Comment: For starters, you *cannot* use `fgets()` to read binary data.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) If you can use a different language and/or a higher-level HTTP library, then you probably should.  2) Otherwise, Google for some C-language/socket examples.  3) Please post back with what you find, and subsequent questions you might have.  Once you find an alternative to `fgets()`.

Comment: @paulsm4 Hello, I have to use C. All socket examples that I found online are to simple. I can for Example download that .png and open it with `fopen` and then read the data with `rb`. Would this be good start?

Comment: Q: Did you get this working?  If not, Q: Is there any reason you have to use "C"?  Q: Can you use C libraries like [libCurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is more complex than just "byte order".

The Good News is that byte order is *probably irrelevant*.  The code you've got now should work just fine sending and receiving text strings with the server.

The Bad News is that you need to connect *differently* if you want to read *binary* data from the server.  Several considerations:

- It sounds like you probably don't need to worry about "POST", "PUT" ... or anything but "GET".
- It also sounds like you don't need to worry about "MIME Types" or "uuencoding/decoding" - you'll just be reading the data as-is.
- You should *definitely* read the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers from the server's HTTP response.
- Perhaps the simplest approach is just call `fgetc()` in a loop if you're reading binary data.  Use `fgets()` for strings, and `fgetc()` for `Content-Length` bytes to read the image.
- You'll probably want to do an `fopen()` to write the image bytes to a file.
- But calling fgets() eliminates the need to worry about "byte order".

Look [here](https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/http-server-what-do-you-need-to-know-to-build-a-simple-http-server-from-scratch-d1ef8945e4fa), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763469/display-image-from-web-server-in-c) and [here](http://jkorpela.fi/forms/cgic.html) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't make a whole lot of sense to write out the image's bytes before deciding which order they should be in.  What would be your next line be, `fopen()`?

---

If you're doing something architecture dependent like this, it's best to guard the case-specific sections with `#if`/*`#elif`*, and use `#else` to emit `#error` with a diagnostic message.
If everything is *supposed to* still work, it can just be `#warning`... but do put the warning in.  For later, when it stops working.

Configuration macros you can test should include `#ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__` and `#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__`; you can see what else is available by 'compiling' with `-E -dD`.  *[there will be a lot; grep is your friend]*

Oh, and "big endian" means if you're reading bytes in address order *(a[0], a[1], a[2], ...),* then the byte at this end is the most significant/highest 'digit'.  Hence  "big-endian".

edit: this may also be of concern...

```c
FILE *sockfile = fdopen(sockfd, "r+");                     // "r+"
if (sockfile == NULL)
    ERROR_EXIT("fdopen: %s\n", strerror(errno));

if (fputs("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n", sockfile) == EOF)      // fputs...
```